# How do I get the inputs of the div that triggered the event?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Basically I want to use the "this" property to get the nested inputs.

I have a group of collapsable elements using Bootstrap with form data. I want to check for null data whenever a user collapses a div. I used JQuery to trigger an event, but I don't know how to get the input just from the div that triggered the event.

```
<div id="accordion" class="panel-group">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#Q1-body">
        Question Group 1
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="Q1-body" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-content">
        <input type="text" name="Q1"></input>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#Q2-body">
        Question Group 1
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="Q2-body" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-content">
        <input type="text" name="Q2"></input>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I set up JQuery to look at the inputs once a user collapses it.

```
  <script> 
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".collapse").on('hidden.bs.collapse',function(){
      var i = 0;
      $(this + ":input").each(function(){
        //some code
      });
    });
});
</script>
```

I get an error when I try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery can accept second parameter like this. So you can use `this` in this way.

**Code snippets:**

```
$(".collapse").on('hidden.bs.collapse',function(){
   var i = 0;
   $(":input", this).each(function(){
     //some code
   });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that jquery selector valid? You can try this.

```
$(this).find(':input').each(function(){
    //some code
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to concatenate a DOM element (`this`) with the string ":input" and then using that as a jQuery selector. (i.e. what you are doing in the line `$(this + ":input")`). Won't work. `this` will be the element that carries the `collapse` class, so the input you are after will be a child.

Something like the following should be more what you are after:

```
  <script> 
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".collapse").on('hidden.bs.collapse',function(){
      var i = 0;
      $(this).find(":input").each(function(){
        //some code
      });
    });
});
</script>
```